# How would I get my links to change color when hovering over li?

Tags: html, css

When I hover over my links the actual links only change color if I hover over them directly. Anyway I can make the text change color when I hover over the actual li instead? Thanks.

I'm still learning so if you see faults in my code please let me know. Cheers!

```css
body {
  background: url('bg.jpg');
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

nav {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  width: 80%;
  height: 60px;  
  margin: 200px auto auto auto;
}

nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: auto;
}

nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 60px;
  float: right;
}

nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #b0b0b0;
  font-family: 'verdana', sans-serif;
  padding: 0 20px;
  font-size: 0.85em;


}

nav a:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
  transition: color 0.8s ease;
}

nav li:hover {
  background-color: #5db0c6;
}

#head-image {
  background: url('land.png');
  width: 80%;
  height: 400px;
  margin: auto;
}

#second-header {
  width: 80%;
  height: 60px;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

#third-header {
  width: 80%;
  height: 700px;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #ededed;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>site</title>
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Libre+Franklin' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!--[if lt IE 8]>
<![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="">Gamerscoin</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Testimonials</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="">RS3</a></li>
        <li><a href="">RS7</a></li>
        <li><a href="">CSGO</a></li>
        <li><a href="">POE</a></li>
        <li><a href="">LoL</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Path of Exile</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Habbo</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <div id="head-image"></div>
    <div id="second-header"></div>
    <div id="third-header"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `li:hover { color: #myDifferentColor; }`. Your links would need to inherit this, so `a { color: inherit; }`

Answer (score 4):

Use the CSS selector `nav li:hover a` instead. This is essentially saying that when the li in the nav is hovered over change the a element inside the li.

The property now looks like:

```
nav li:hover a{
    color: #ffffff;
    transition: color 0.8s ease;
}
```

```css
body {
    background: url('bg.jpg');
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

nav {
background-color: #ffffff;
    width: 80%;
    height: 60px;       
    margin: 200px auto auto auto;
}

nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: auto;
}

nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 60px;
    float: right;
}

nav a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #b0b0b0;
    font-family: 'verdana', sans-serif;
    padding: 0 20px;
    font-size: 0.85em;


}

nav li:hover a{
    color: #ffffff;
    transition: color 0.8s ease;
}

nav li:hover {
    background-color: #5db0c6;

}

#head-image {
    background: url('land.png');
    width: 80%;
    height: 400px;
    margin: auto;
}

#second-header {
    width: 80%;
    height: 60px;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

#third-header {
    width: 80%;
    height: 700px;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: #ededed;


}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

  <title>site</title>

  <meta name="description" content="" />

  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Libre+Franklin' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!--[if lt IE 8]>
  <![endif]-->

</head>
<body>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">Gamerscoin</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Testimonials</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="">RS3</a></li>
            <li><a href="">RS7</a></li>
            <li><a href="">CSGO</a></li>
            <li><a href="">POE</a></li>
            <li><a href="">LoL</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Path of Exile</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Habbo</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
<div id="head-image"></div>
<div id="second-header"></div>
<div id="third-header"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
nav li:hover a {
    color: #b0b0b0;
}
```

Comment: Why are you setting the hover on the list item, and not the link?

Comment: The OP asked for the link colour to change when the list item was hovered over.

Answer (score 0):

The downside of simply changing the `color` of your links when hovering their parents is that it will give the impression that the entite `li` is clickable, which it won't be. To get around this, set the `display` property of your links to `block`, forcing the links to occupy the full space available in their parents.

```css
nav {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    width: 80%;
    height: 60px;
    margin: 200px auto auto auto;
}
nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: auto;
}
nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 60px;
    float: right;
}
nav a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #b0b0b0;
    font-family: 'verdana', sans-serif;
    padding: 0 20px;
    font-size: 0.85em;
}
nav a:hover {
    background-color: #5db0c6;
    color: #ffffff;
    transition: color 0.8s ease;
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="">Gamerscoin</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Testimonials</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="">RS3</a></li>
        <li><a href="">RS7</a></li>
        <li><a href="">CSGO</a></li>
        <li><a href="">POE</a></li>
        <li><a href="">LoL</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Path of Exile</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Habbo</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can still use tag names after `hover` command like this:

```
nav li:hover a{

color: #ffffff;
transition: color 0.8s ease;

}
```